# Get region base URL (HC_HOST) in the SAP Cloud Platform Cloud Foundry environment

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-platform

In the SAP Cloud Platform Neo environment, there is a system property `HC_HOST` which contains the base URL of the SAP Cloud Platform region where the application is deployed (see [documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/d553d78bf9bd4ecbac201b873f557db6.html)).

Is there something similar for the Cloud Foundry environment? I checked `cf env`, but I couldn't see anything obvious.

Comment: There is no such env variable in CF ....may you be you can put them yourself in cf env and refer from there

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to NEO environment variables in CF are [VCAP](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html) environment variables. I think the closest to *HC_HOST* in *NEO* is *VCAP_APPLICATION.uris*.
Although, you will need to extract base uri from the application uri.